# How to login to Docker registries using Github Actions

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

Im trying to push a docker image to public docker repository using github actions following their documentation but I cant make it work:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/docker/login@master
        with: # Set the secret as an input
          DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
        env: # Set the secret in the env
          DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Test
        run: mvn clean verify -U
      - name: build
        run: ./mvnw compile jib:dockerBuild
      - name: push
        run:  docker push odfsoft/guess-game:latest
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/docker run --name bb8146f4246c56a44203bb2667ccfbdcab81_f18969 --label 04bb81 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e DOCKER_USERNAME -e DOCKER_PASSWORD -e INPUT_DOCKER_USERNAME -e INPUT_DOCKER_PASSWORD -e HOME -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/spring-boot-guess-game/spring-boot-guess-game":"/github/workspace" 04bb81:46f4246c56a44203bb2667ccfbdcab81
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

is this something related to my action or a limitation in github actions?

Comment: Future readers: Note the spelling mistake in `DOCKER_PASSWPORD`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `actions/docker` action has now been deprecated. If you visit the repository you will see that the repository is archived and has the following message.

> This action is deprecated in favor of using the run script step in the new YAML language to run the docker cli.

https://github.com/actions/docker

So the recommended way to login to Docker registries is to use the `run` script command as follows.

For the public DockerHub registry:

```
name: my workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Login to DockerHub Registry
        run: echo ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }} | docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }} --password-stdin
```

For a private registry, such as the new GitHub Package Registry, you also need to specify the hostname:

```
name: my workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Login to GitHub Package Registry
        run: echo "${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}" | docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u "${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}" --password-stdin
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58350578/new-location-of-docker-actions/58350591#58350591) for complete workflow examples of docker image publishing.

Comment: I got this error:: Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

Comment: @SudipBhandari You get that error when you forget `` --password-stdin`` .
``echo "${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}" | docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u "${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}" --password-stdin``

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/docker-login

Try this action instead as `actions/docker/login@master` appears to have been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I found Git hub action: Build and push Docker images

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images

It works well, I was able to build and push docker image to Docker Hub.

Answer (score 1):

For service containers, see this example:

```
jobs:
  build:
    container:
      image: octocat/ci-image:latest
      credentials:
        username: mona
        password: ${{ secrets.docker_hub_password}}
    services:
      db:
        image:  ghcr.io/octocat/testdb:latest
        credentials:
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ghcr_password }}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `docker/login-action@v1` to login to docker registry https://github.com/docker/login-action.

```
name: deploy
    
    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - main
    
    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - uses: docker/login-action@v1
            with:
              registry: private-registry-url
              username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME  }}
              password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
```

Answer (score -5):

For logging in to dockerhub you can use the action provided in the [actions/docker repo](https://github.com/actions/docker/tree/master/login).

Which looks like this:

```
action "Docker Login" {
  uses = "actions/docker/login@master"
  secrets = ["DOCKER_USERNAME", "DOCKER_PASSWORD"]
}
```

Comment: HCL has been deprecated in favor of yaml: https://help.github.com/en/articles/migrating-github-actions-from-hcl-syntax-to-yaml-syntax

Comment: yeah this was the example that I found earlier on but this does not work anymore because now you need to use yaml. btw I didnt down vote you.