# Publish docker image to jfrog artifactory from github actions CICD pipeline

Tags: github-actions, docker-push

I am implementing CICD pipeline with github actions. I want to publish the docker image to jfrog artifactory. Does anybody has any idea how to implement that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New location of docker actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58350578/new-location-of-docker-actions)

Comment: Follow the steps in link provided on my first comment but change the docker github registry to the artifactory registry and you should be good to go

Comment: want to use jfrog cli to publish image to jfrog artifactory with jfrog access token. I have generated token and used in github actions CI pipeline, but it throws error like '[Error] illegal base64 data at input byte 119' and later '[Error] invalid character 'e' looking for beginning of value'

Answer (score 12):

A complete sample with login, build and push to a jfrog artifactory.

This sample exepected a Dockerfile at the root of the repository, and secrets stored in GitHub Secrets.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up QEMU ️
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx 
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Login to JFrog   
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: <your artifactory>.jfrog.io
          username: ${{ secrets.JFROG_USER_WRITER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.JFROG_PASSWORD_WRITER }}

      - name: Build and push 
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: <your artifactory>.jfrog.io/<your image name>:latest
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to log into the registry without using the jfrog cli with docker login. F.e:

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Login to DockerHub Registry
        run: docker login -u ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }} -p ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }} artifactory.<yourcompanyrepo>.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [the docker-login github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/docker-login), you could specify the registry.

F.e.

- name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
  uses: docker/login-action@v1
  with:
  registry: artifactory..com
  username: user
  password: pass

Answer (score 0):

An easier attitude would be using the JFrog CLI and the Setup JFrog CLI GitHub Action:

1. In your local machine, configure and export your JFrog server:

```
# Interactively, create a new server
jfrog c add

# Create a server token. This token can be used as a secret in your workflow named: "JF_ARTIFACTORY_SECRET".
jfrog c export
```

2. Run the Setup JFrog CLI GitHub Action:

```yaml
- uses: jfrog/setup-jfrog-cli@v1
  env:
    JF_ARTIFACTORY: ${{ secrets.JF_ARTIFACTORY_SECRET }}
- run: |
    jfrog rt docker-push <image tag> <target repo>
    
    # Optional - publish build info to Artifactory
    jfrog rt bp
```

Read more about it:

- [Setup JFrog CLI](https://github.com/jfrog/setup-jfrog-cli#setup-jfrog-cli) - Full documentation of the GitHub Action.
- [Download JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/getcli/) - Download the JFrog CLI to your machine to create the required secret.
- [Managing Docker Images in the CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-ManagingDockerImages) - JFrog CLI Documentation

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Quentin,

You might face an error while running `Docker Buildx` step saying:

```bash
Error response from daemon: manifest for not found: manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry
```

The solution for this problem is to run `docker context create builders` in a separate step then use the created `builders` within `Docker Buildx` step as following:

```yaml
...

- name: Set up Docker Context for Buildx
  id: buildx-context
  run: |
    docker context create builders

- name: Set up Docker Buildx
  uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
  with:
    version: latest
    endpoint: builders
...
```