# How to login pull registry at Github Action for services

Tags: docker, github, docker-registry, github-actions

I want to have a `services` section for Github Actions workflow file with a private registry. The simplified config looks like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  my_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      image-name:
        image: docker.pkg.github.com/<org>/<repo>/<image>

    steps:
    # ...
```

The repo resides within the same organization, if it matters. Also the image can be pulled with a proper credentials locally, but obviously fails at github actions pipeline with an error:

`Error response from daemon: Get <image_url>: no basic auth credentials`

So my question is: is it possible to specify credentials either via env vars (aka *Secrets* in Github), or maybe some flag for `services.options` exists? I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226756/how-to-login-to-docker-registries-using-github-actions) can be an alternative with manual login/pulling/starting, but I would prefer declarative way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Sept. 24th 2020, yes, it should be possible to specify your credentials for a private registry.

See "[GitHub Actions: Private registry support for job and service containers](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-24-github-actions-private-registry-support-for-job-and-service-containers/)"

> You can now use images from private registeries in [job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) and [service](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservices) containers.
>
> Here's an example of using private images from Docker Hub:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    container:
      image: octocat/ci-image:latest
      credentials:
        username: mona
        password: ${{ secrets.docker_hub_password}}
    services:
      db:
        image:  octocat/testdb:latest
        credentials:
          username: mona
          password: ${{ secrets.docker_hub_password }}
```